# Is there any way to get content-length without getting response body

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HttpClient to download content from the server. I want to check the size before downloading content. I have used HTTPGet to download content and before processing the inputstream I am checking the content-length header but I see HTTPGet will download the body too even though we do not process.

```
var httpGet = httpGet(url);
try (final var closeableHttpResponse = closeableHttpClient.execute(httpGet);) {
    final var statusCode = closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    final var headers = getHeadersMap(closeableHttpResponse.getAllHeaders());
    final var contentLength = Long.valueOf(headers.get("content-length"));
    final var entity = closeableHttpResponse.getEntity();
    if (<<contentLength validation>>)) {
        // Not to process
    } else {
    
        final var inputstream = entity.getContent();
        // Processing inputstream
        EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(entity);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Error Handling
}
```

1. If I use HTTP Head it will give only headers. Is it a correct approach to determining response size?
2. There are some cases in which the content-length header doesn't have length. Is there any other way too for determine size before downloading if the content-length header doesn't have a length?

Comment: Why not doing HEAD instead of GET? This is what HEAD is for.

Comment: Ok, thank you. is there any way to handle content length if the response is chunked where content length does not exist upfront?

Comment: no, there is not